# Exporting SSRS reports into csv changes the £ to a ? but is intact when exporting from VS2019

Tags: reporting-services, report

SQL server/SSRS 2016

I have Googled the interwebs but to no solution, so any input will be welcomed.

When exporting through Report Manager the £ symbol in the csv changes to a ? but when doing the same from Visual Studio it remains intact as  £.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Report manager encodes the .csv file differently than visual studio

The generated CSV file uses a UTF-8 character encoding, but Excel tries to read it using a different encoding.  If you need to use the generated CSV file from Report Manager

Try this:

**Option 1**

1. Open in notepad
2. Save the file
3. Open in Excel

**Option 2**

1. Open Excel
2. Import .csv file using Data-->Import External Data --> Import Data
3. Select the file type of "csv" and browse to your file
4. In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 UTF" (or choose correct language character identifier)
   5.Change the Delimiter to comma
5. Select where to import to and Finish

Comment: Thanks Aaron, the issue is that the report is delivered to a share on the server as a subscription so won't be convenient to use your method.

Comment: ah, bummer. Not sure on your access but you could talk to your SQL Server admin, and see if he can adjust the RSReportServer.config file and change the encoding. however the benefit of UTF-8 is that its backwards compatible with ASCII.  Option 2 - could you create an excel file that pulls from the .csv for the end user ? (might be a bit beyond your scope -but could be a workaround)

Comment: Thanks again Aaron, will look into that